# Why would I want to use my data this way, and what am I supposed to do with this regression?

Tags: regression, econometrics

I'm writing an essay on the effects of M&A announcements on stock prices. I understand most of the requirements perfectly fine, but I'm stumped on one particular part of the essay.

I have for every target and acquiror stock prices in the range [-170, 10] days, where day 0 is the announcement date. I use [-170, -71] to calculate the abnormal returns in [-10, 10] which is the event window I'm interested in. The next part confuses me:

The idea underlying the in-between period [-70, -11] is that for each firm/stock 4 variables can be con-structed, that is the stock-price runup = stock return [-70, -11], the stock-sigma = stock vola-tility [-70, -11], the market-price runup = market return [-70, -11], and the market-sigma = market volatility [-70, -11].

Following this, I'm supposed to use these four variables for both univariate and multivariate regressions for CAR[K,L] where [K,L] will be chosen depending on the number of days for which a significant announcement effect has been found.

My question is: why would I want to have this in my essay, I have literally no idea why this would be interesting. What is the purpose of the four variables, and why can the be used to regress on the CAR?

I know this is quite an economical question, but I think the theory is statistical in nature, and there is not an economics stackexchange-site, so I decided to ask this question here. If anyone could provide any assistance, even the smallest hint, I would be most grateful. Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Sounds as if you should be asking the person who gave the assignment.

Comment: Yes, true. It was worded as if it were a very obvious thing, so I thought I'd look around first.